# out of memory error is raise when i scrolling in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

When I put images in the grid view after completing this task images are successfully loaded in my grid view but when I scroll down it throws an out of memory error in logcat.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView iv;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        iv= new ImageView(mcontext);
        WindowManager wm =    (WindowManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int height=display.getHeight()/2;
        int width=display.getWidth()/2;
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width,width));
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }
    byte[] stringimage = Base64.decode(images.get(position),Base64.DEFAULT);
    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stringimage,0,stringimage.length));
    return iv;
}
```

Comment: btw, you don't have to don't have to do display width/height calculations in every iteration. Somewhere in constructor is enough. WHat is the size of images Arrray? How large images are you trying to load? You should probably include some scaling before loading imageview

Comment: You should use SoftReference for bitmaps example: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is exactly what you would expect. Android allocates some memory for your program. As you scroll through your grid, you might need more space for new images. If your images are too large, you could run out of memory.

Try reducing the sizes of your Bitmap before loading the entire thing into memory.

You can use `BitmapFactory.Options` to request that the image is not loaded into memory using `inJustDecodeBounds`. This will tell you how large the image is, and you can scale it as you want to.

Something like this:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    //inJustDecodeBounds as true ensures bitmap is not loaded into memory
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(somePath, options);
    int width= options.outWidth;
    int height= options.outHeight;
```

Now you have the height and width, and can try to determine if the image is too large for its imageview. Remember that while a picture taken with a camera can be something like 1920x1080 pixels, your imageview might only show 200x100 pixels or something. No reason to load all the pixels.

Comment: but can you give me some other option to store a image in a cache memory? because i see log cat when i set a image to bitmap then heap size is increase so that why i want to use a caching option